# test.starttest() and test.stoptest() not working

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, class, failing-tests

Please let me know how to resolve the below issue.I am new to salesforce,its still giving me an error Too many DML statements: 151.Using Test.starttest() and test.stoptest() is not working.

```
Test Class:-

    public TestMethod static void Test_1(){
            test.startTest();
            
            id idvar;
            for(integer i=0;i<160;i++){
            account accobj=new account();
            accobj.name='TestAccount';
            accobj.CustomPhone__c='123';
            accobj.date_today__c=date.today();
            
            insert accobj;
            idvar=accobj.Id;
             }
                  
            
            test.stopTest();
            
            SampleClass sampleClObj=new SampleClass();
        }
```

Comment: Your issue comes from your insert statement in the loop and SF limits. NEVER use DML statement in loop, always put all objects that need to be saved in a list and use one DML statement after the loop!

Comment: @BorisGichev Thanks for the info,i got your point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Salesforce has a governor [limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm)! In a single apex execution context, you can only do 150 DML operations.

Being a beginner to apex I suggest you read through some of the best practices highlighted [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/wiki/apex_code_best_practices)

Instead of doing DML in a loop, use `List` to collect all objects and perform one DML instead.

```
 @isTest
 public static void testScenario(){

    List<Account> lstaccount = new List<Account>(); // collect all records to perform DML
    id idvar;
    for(integer i=0;i<160;i++){
       account accobj=new account();
       accobj.name='TestAccount';
       accobj.CustomPhone__c='123';
       accobj.date_today__c=date.today();
      lstaccount.add(accobj);
    }
        
    insert lstaccount; // DML outside loop
        
    idvar=lstaccount[0].Id;
              
    test.startTest();
       SampleClass sampleClObj=new SampleClass();// rest of what you want to test
    test.stopTest();
  }
```

Also looks like you are new to Apex Testing as well! This trailhead [module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_testing) can help you get up to speed.

I also lately did [live](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hi2A0N0dFFg&list=PLgIMQe2PKPSK7myo5smEv2ZtHbnn7HyHI) streaming on Trailhead, so you can watch it to learn how to create a proper test class.